# How to solve this geometry problem involving circles and tangents?

Tags: geometry

In triangle ABC the angle at A is 60 and the inscribed circle touches AB at
the point D. If AD = 5 and DB = 3, find the length of BC. 
[image]

I know BD = BE since they are tangents and AD = AF but this is the furthest I've reached into solving this problem but I can't think of anything else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $O$ be the center of the inscribed circle. Then $\Delta ADO$ forms a 30-90-60 $\Delta$. Hence you get the radius $r$ of the inscribed circle. Use this in $\Delta OBE$ to get angle $B$ and hence angle $C$ and hence $EC$.

Comment: how do I get the radius $r$ of the circle? if you are saying that $ΔADO$ forms a 30-90-60 then how do I proceed from there?

Comment: $AD$ is given and you know $\angle OAD$. Using trigonometric formula for $\tan$ you can calculate $r$.

Comment: But I do not know the value for AO nor do I know the value for OD. Also, I am not allowed to use a calculator.

Comment: $\tan \angle OAD = \tan 30 = \frac{OD}{AD}$ Therefore $r = \frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}$

Comment: OK. I know now that $OE$ = $r$. Now how do I proceed? I cannot get the value of angle B without a calculator and I am not allowed to use one. Also, the memorandum says that that BC = 13, but I do not know how to get that answer. Please can you show me how you get the value of BC?

Comment: $\tan \angle OBE = \frac{r}{BE} = \frac{5}{3 \sqrt{3}}$

Comment: Now $\angle OEC = \angle C/2$. Hence, $\tan C/2 = \cot (A/2 + B/2) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{3}}$ using standard trig formulae. $\tan C/2 = \frac{r}{EC}$. Therefore $EC = 10$. Hence the answer $BC = 13$.

Comment: I have no idea what is happening at that cot part, I do not know that much math because I am only 16 but thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: OK. You must surely know that $\tan(90 - \theta) = \cot \theta$. This has been used. Also $\tan (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\tan \alpha + \tan \beta}{1 - \tan \alpha \tan \beta}$. Thats all you need to know

Comment: Believe it or not, I didn't. I know that $\frac{1}{tan\Theta } = cot\Theta $ .I only know basic trig ($sin, cos, tan$) and I do know the reciprocal functions but none of their identities. You shouldn't expect me to know that much trig as I said, I am only 16.

Comment: Maybe because I knew these when I was 14. Anyways, its good to read these things as they are extremely useful in solving geometry problems.

Answer (score 0):

there is property of circle construction :Inscribe a Circle in a Triangle

```
Steps:

Bisect one of the angles
Bisect another angle
Where they cross is the center of the inscribed circle
```

now if you bisect one angle  ,namely angle $A$,but this also would be  right triangle,because
The angle between the tangent and radius is 90°,example
[image]

and you can easily proceed from here

Answer (score 0):

The tangents CF and CE are also equal - call their value $x$,  then apply the cosine rule. The extent of the trigonometry required is knowing that $\cos(60) = \frac{1}{2}$.